# Grouping and renaming based on date

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a working query that produces a table with two columns.

```
SELECT months, count(user_id) as count
        from 
        (
        select u.user_id, u.region_id, u.latest_login, year(u.latest_login), 
        period_diff(date_format(now(), '%Y%m'),date_format(u.latest_login, '%Y%m')) as months
        from users u
        where u.date_ended = 0000-00-00 
            AND country_id = 1 
            AND intRoleId = 3 
        )
        t1
        group by months;
```

It produces this table:

[image: Two Column Table]

I want to make groups based on the amount of months. I have checked documentation and the below query seems to be what I need, but I get a syntax error. I've tried changing the format of the logic and naming conventions but not sure what is going wrong here.

```
SELECT months, count(user_id) as count,
        sum(months=<2) as 'Less than 3 months',
        sum(months>2 and months=<5) as '3-6 months',
        sum(months>5 and months=<11) as '6-12 months',
        sum(months>11 and months=<24) as '12-24 months',
        sum(months>24 and months<20000) as 'More than 24 months',
        sum(months>20000) as 'Never'
        from 
        (
        select u.user_id, u.region_id, u.latest_login, year(u.latest_login), 
        
        period_diff(date_format(now(), '%Y%m'),date_format(u.latest_login, '%Y%m')) as months
        
        from users u
        where u.date_ended = 0000-00-00 
            AND country_id = 1 
            AND intRoleId = 3
        
        group by months
         
        )
        t1;
```

Thanks so much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

To escape column names, use double quotes not single quotes.  However, I would recommend names that don't need to be escaped.  Also, convert the boolean values to numbers

```
 select months, count(user_id) as count,
        sum( (months=<2)) as months_less_than_3_,
        sum( (months>2 and months=<5)) as months_3_6,
        sum( (months>5 and months=<11)) as months_6_12,
        sum( (months>11 and months=<24)) as months_12_24,
        sum( (months>24 and months<20000)) as months_25_plus,
        sum( (months>20000)) as Never
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I am still getting the same error when substituting that code in though:

Query 1 ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '<2)::int ) as months_less_than_3_,
        sum( (months>2 and months=<5)::int ) ' at line 2

Comment: @astara303 . . . Did you change the tag on the question?  I'm pretty sure it was originally Postgres.

Comment: Ah no I didnt change that, but your advice still very appreciated thank you! I realised once I got it working that sum isn't going to work for this query anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Ah I realised the issue! Knew it would be something I just didn't know to google. You can't put the equals sign before the less than/more than sign. Thank you for the reply